# How to use x2x options completeregion[left|right|low|up] - debian

Tags: linux

I don't understand how to use the `completeregion[left|right|low|up]` options of x2x - it always traps the mouse in a single row on :to screen.

For eg:

```
DISPLAY=:0.0 ssh -Y -i .ssh/id_bar  bar /home/foo/x2x/x2x   -completeregionleft 0 -completeregionright 3286 -completeregionup 1080 -completeregionlow 0 -geometry 1440x900  -west -to :0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

x2x doesn't have a very good manual page.

The problem you have with it being stuck on one-line is that the Xorg vertical Y axis increases going down. So your command line would be

```
-completeregionup 0 -completeregionlow 1080
```

The -geometry argument is only to be used if you don't use north, south, east or west. It pops up a X window which, when you click in it, will activate the mouse and keyboard on the "to" desktop. To leave that desktop, you have to press two mouse buttons whilst over the x2x X window on the "from" desktop. (The mouse still moves over your home "from" desktop whilst in the remote "to" desktop.)

It's a good idea to use it once with the window, because it helps to understand how x2x works: it scales your own "from" desktop and projects it onto the "to" desktop. So, if you have two displays that aren't the same resolution, you will get a dead zone on "to" desktop. For me, I have a 1280x1024 on the left, and a 1366x768 on the right and they are aligned on their bottom edges. When this is projected onto the remote "to" desktop (originally a 1440x900), it left a block in the top-right corner that the mouse couldn't reach.

I've tried to work around this with the completeregion switches and got nowhere.

I found that if I managed to match my "to" desktop resolution with one of my from desktops and used the "-noscale" feature. I managed to get access to the whole "to" desktop. So I switched the remote down to 1280x1024 and used -noscale with -east and got a good layout.

So I run this on my work "from" desktop with the two monitors.

```
x2x -noscale -to my-remote:0.0 -east
```

(Of course, you've managed to enable the TCP and managed the access control. Another couple of gotchas that could be mentioned in the manual page.)